# symfony2 and facebook share button

Tags: facebook, symfony

i'm working on a web app, and I added a facebook like/share button by following [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button). I was wondering, is there a way to catch the event in the controller, if someone shares the page ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to retrieve data passively (ie. just count the likes or retrieve the cookie of the liker), you can catch the click event with JS and make an ajax call to your controller.

To completely catch the event and tweak it before sending it to FB, you can hack the behaviour of the button to make it point directly to your controller, and then send the request to facebook yourself via your own custom method.

The code generated by FB's like buttons is not that simple though, so I would stick to the first method if I were you.